# Component style doesn't work as it should (NextJS and TailwindCSS)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm creating style for a component and it doesnt work as it should, I'm trying do this grid:

[image: Grid]

Footer.tsx

```
<div className="bg-light flex justify-center items-start p-9 gap-10">
  {menuItems.map((menu, index) => (
    <div
      key={index}
      className={`flex ${
        index >= 2 && index <= 4 ? "flex-row gap-5" : "flex-col"
      } justify-center items-start`}
    >
      <MenuItem title={menu.title} items={menu.items} />
    </div>
  ))}
</div>;
```

MeuItem.tsx

```
interface MenuItemsProps {
  title: string;
  items: string[];
  className?: string;
}

const MenuItem: React.FC<MenuItemsProps> = ({ title, items }) => (
  <div className={`flex justify-center items-start gap-3 flex-col`}>
    <p className={`footer-heading`}>{title}</p>
    {items.map((item, index) => (
      <p className="footer-body" key={index}>
        {item}
      </p>
    ))}
  </div>
);

export default MenuItem;
```

The result of this code looks like this:

[image: Result]

I know I need to put the flex-col in the parent div, but how do I do that? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You have to group all items with index<2 in one variable and the rest in another. Then assign a property to the group such as direction: “flex-col”.

Now all you have to do is encapsulate you logic in flex col, loop over the items in group 1 and group 2 based on “direction” prop.